# No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie warning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am running Rails 3.2.3, Ruby 1.9 under Fedora 17.  I get this warning, when I run `rails s`, and how do I fix?

> SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
>      This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
>      provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
>      cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
>      future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

Comment: Is a value set in config/initializers/secret_token.rb?

Comment: Kashyap - yes, a value is set.

Comment: I've got same warning after upgrading Rails from 3.2.9 to 3.2.10

Comment: Actually this warning was added to Rack 1.4.2 which was released on rubygems.org just yesterday (6 Jan 2013) but actual commit was done on 18 March 2012.

Comment: Yeah,just today i too got such warning

Comment: downgrade to: `gem 'rack', '1.4.1'`

Comment: If you can't run guard+spork+rspec, downgrade as well.

Comment: @Marlin I changed the tag - still there should be some solution for RoR 3.1 as well.. Maybe make it another question?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

> This is a Rails bug, as the subclass is violating the superclass API contract.
>
> **The warning can be safely ignored by Rails users.**

(https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/485#issuecomment-11956708, emphasis added)

Confirmation on the rails bug discussion: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7372#issuecomment-11981397

Comment: Update your rails gems as this is backported to all supported rails gems. note @henrik-n

Answer (score 20):

Reading the discussion based on tehgeekmeisters answer, this warning is popping up as Rails is using Rack cookies in a different way than intended. It should be ok to just ignore this warning for now until there is a final agreement on how to handle this issue and a fix in place.

Answer (score 17):

This issue has been worked around in the just released Rails 3.2.11.

Log: https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/v3.2.11

Commit: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/95fe9ef945a35f56fa1c3ef356aec4a3b868937c

Comment: @Dreyfuzz Note that 3.2.11 is later than 3.2.2 (since it's 11, not 1.1). So just upgrading Rails may fix your problem.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I got stuck thinking in decimal notation where 3.2.2 is the same as 3.2.20. Thought I was on the bleeding edge there for a minute!

Answer (score 16):

*rails 3.2.9 - ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]*

Hello everyone, the following has worked for me, it may work for you.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb
```

```
module Compatibility
          def initialize(app, options = {})
            options[:key]     ||= '_session_id'
            #fixed warning - SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
            options[:secret] ||= Rails.application.config.secret_token
            super
          end
    end
```

Comment: This is the answer with the least of the "up votes", but the very only answer that **actually** solves the problem, without downgrading, and having compatibility issues. It just clears the annoying message

Comment: Rather not patching the rails code. I think this better to be resolved in the release. upgrading to 3.2.11 would be better than modifying rails code.

Answer (score 6):

Downgrading to rack 1.4.1 should be sufficient to solve this for now.  <strike>There's [an issue open](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8789) for this and I just submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8792) that seems to fix it for me.  In any case, watch the issue, and you should be able to upgrade to rack 1.4.2 after this is fixed.</strike>

Apparently, there's ongoing discussion about how to fix this on another [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7372).  You'll have to either downgrade to 1.4.1, ignore it, or figure out your own fix until this is dealt with (and backported, if that even happens).

Answer (score 5):

An issue has been opened in Github https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8789. It appears that a bug involving Rails 3.2.10 with Rack 1.4.2 is causing this. IMO, it can be safely ignored till the issue is resolved.

**EDIT**: This issue has been resolved in Rails 3.2.11.

Answer (score 3):

rails update to 3.2.13 ,can solve this question.