# Can't convert nil into Hash when running spork after Rails update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I upgraded my Rails to 3.2.11. If I run rspec, it passes all the test. If I run the server, it seems to work fine. However when I run guard (which uses spork), the rspec in guard will fail to load the Rails environment.

When I run `bundle exec guard` and when it is trying to run rspec, the following error will occur while loading Rails:

> Exception encountered: #

The stack trace doesn't make much sense to me.

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:85:in `initialize'  
code/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'  
code/spec/spec_helper.rb:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

The spec_helper is the normal one which I got from the internet, and just loads Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that Rack gets updated to 1.4.3 during the past few days. And according to this [No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374871/no-secret-option-provided-to-racksessioncookie-warning) there is some problem with Rails.

If I force to use rack 1.4.1 then there will be no problem.