# Ruby on Rails Type Error cant convert nil into hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started a new application with

```
rails new doctor

rake db:migrate

rails generate controller home index

rails generate scaffold Patient age:string city:string number:string street:string
```

after that i deletet the public index and changed the route to  root :to => "home#index"

```
rake db:migrate

rails server
```

So my problem is that i become the error in the Browser:

Type error,   cant convert nil into hash

I cant explain me, what should be wrong in my application! I hope somebody knows the answer! Thanks

```
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:28:in `merge!'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:28:in `initialize'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:242:in `new'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:242:in `prepare_session'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:209:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__759447931__call__819038987__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: can you show us the codes in your `index` action?

Comment: <h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>

Comment: So far i added noting, its the standard text

Comment: ok, then which line shows the error? how about posting the stack trace?

Comment: It dont says in wich line, only Rails.root: C:/Sites/doctor                 The trace is to long for an comment! Sorry

Comment: @EmSta you can post full trace in your question

Comment: @EmSta Is error only for `home#index` ??? Try opening `patients/index`

Comment: Its always the same ! Its so crazy!

Comment: @EmSta I think some problem with your `webrick` server. Before changing `routes` your app was running correctly ????

Comment: @EmSta Try creating some dummy app. Run server and open default rails page. Tell me is it giving any error ??

Comment: Thats what i tried 10 seconds ago! I dont see any other solutions than delete ruby on rails from my computer and install it new!

Comment: Can you update rails gem? I don't know haw you install Rails on Windows, but I see you use Rails 3.2.1, which might be kind old (1 year old), maybe you found bug in them. http://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions

Comment: Also - I rerun your steps with Rails 3.2.1 in Linux, and everything works without problems, besides warning, which could be ignored: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374871/no-secret-option-provided-to-racksessioncookie-warning/14199380

Comment: So you would say i simply update my version?

Comment: If you can do it, it's probably safest option before reinstalling Rails environment